# Core Plot Scatter plot not plotting and memory increases until crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

Good day, I have an app that displays a single scatter plot. Everything worked but there is a memory increase when the scatter plot is plotted. The data comes from .txt files, converted to Mutable arrays and displayed as a scatter plot. I have tested the arrays and they populate as they should. 
The app loads the data from text files displayed in a table view just before the plot is displayed. 
Could someone please assist me in identifying why the plot does not want to work any more and why the memory usage keeps on increasing.

The tableView selection:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];


NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectoryPath error:NULL];

NSString *filePath = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

sharedManager.selectedFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];


 sharedManager.tappedLine = indexPath.row;// not +1


  [self populateArraysWithFileData:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished) {
        NSLog(@"success");
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"graph" sender:nil]; //view controllers are linked

    }

}];

}
```

Here is the graph.m file:

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
#import "GraphViewController.h"
#import "DataSource.h"
#import "methods.h"


@interface GraphViewController ()

@end


@implementation GraphViewController

NSString *  const CPDTickerSymbol = @"STAR";


@synthesize hostView = hostView_;



#pragma mark - UIViewController lifecycle methods
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self initPlot];

DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];

NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectoryPath error:NULL];

// 2 - Set graph title
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[directoryContent objectAtIndex:sharedManager.tappedLine]];

[self.navigationItem setTitle:title];
sharedManager.labelArray = nil;


[self initPlot];

}



- (NSArray *)tickerSymbols
{
static NSArray *symbols = nil;
if (!symbols)
{
    symbols = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               @"STAR",
               nil];
}
return symbols;
}


#pragma mark - Chart behavior
-(void)initPlot {

[self configureHost];
[self configureGraph];
[self configurePlots];
[self configureAxes];

}

-(void)configureHost {
self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.hostView];
}

-(void)configureGraph {
DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];

// 1 - Create the graph
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectoryPath error:NULL];


// 2 - Set graph title
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[directoryContent objectAtIndex:sharedManager.tappedLine]];
    graph.title = title;

// 3 - Create and set text style
CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(20.0f, 0.0f);


// 4 - Set padding for plot area
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:40.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:10.0f];

// 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
}



-(void)configurePlots {
// 1 - Get graph and plot space
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

// 2 - Create the plot
CPTScatterPlot *magPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
magPlot.dataSource = self;

// Make the plot curved
magPlot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;
magPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbol;
CPTColor *magColor = [CPTColor redColor];
[graph addPlot:magPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

// 3 - Set up plot space
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:magPlot, nil]];
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:@1.1];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:@1.2];
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;


// 4 - Create styles and symbols
CPTMutableLineStyle *magLineStyle = [magPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
magLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
magLineStyle.lineColor = magColor;
magPlot.dataLineStyle = magLineStyle;
CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
symbolLineStyle.lineColor = magColor;
CPTPlotSymbol *symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];
symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:magColor];
symbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;
symbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
magPlot.plotSymbol = symbol;
}



-(void)configureAxes {

// Calculate the increment values for the y-axis
DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];
float ymax = -MAXFLOAT;
float ymin = MAXFLOAT;
for (NSNumber *num in sharedManager.finalFIELDreading) {
    float y = num.floatValue;
    if (y < ymin) ymin = y;
    if (y > ymax) ymax = y;
}
int MinFieldReading = roundf(ymin);
int MaxFieldReading = roundf(ymax);
int diffFieldReading = MaxFieldReading-MinFieldReading;
int Increment = diffFieldReading/[sharedManager.finalFIELDreading count];
int incrementValue = 10 * floor( Increment / 10 + 0.5 );


// 1 - Create styles
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

// 2 - Get axis set
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;

// 3 - Configure x-axis
NSArray *yMinNumbers = [sharedManager.finalFIELDreading sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];// should determine dynamically based on min reading
CGFloat yMin = [yMinNumbers[0] floatValue];

 // Set Axis to start just below the min y value
 axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalPosition = @(yMin);
CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.title = @"Station (m)";
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    x.titleOffset = 15.0f;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;


  CGFloat stationCount = [sharedManager.finalSTNreading count];


    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:stationCount];
    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:stationCount];
    NSInteger i = 0;

    for (NSString *station in sharedManager.finalSTNreading) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:station  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        CGFloat location = i++;
        label.tickLocation = @(location);
        label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
        if (label) {
            [xLabels addObject:label];
            [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
        }
    }

x.axisLabels = xLabels;
x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;


// 4 - Configure y-axis

CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.title = @"Field Reading (nTesla)";
y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
y.titleOffset = 37.0f;
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.labelOffset = -7.0f;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
NSInteger majorIncrement = incrementValue;
NSArray *yMaxNumbers = [sharedManager.finalFIELDreading sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];// should determine dynamically based on max reading
CGFloat yMax = [[yMaxNumbers lastObject] floatValue];
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSInteger j = yMin; j <= (yMax+majorIncrement); j += majorIncrement) {

        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
        NSNumber *location = @(j);
        label.tickLocation = location;
        label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
        if (label) {
            [yLabels addObject:label];
        }
        [yMajorLocations addObject:location];

}
y.axisLabels = yLabels;    
y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
}



-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];
CPTTextLayer *newTextLayer;
newTextLayer = [CPTTextLayer layer];
NSNumber* num = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
if(index < [sharedManager.labelArray count])
{
    num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[sharedManager.labelArray objectAtIndex:index] floatValue]];

    CPTMutableTextStyle *labelTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    labelTextStyle.fontSize = 10.0f;
    labelTextStyle.color = [CPTColor redColor];
    newTextLayer.textStyle = labelTextStyle;
    newTextLayer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i%@",@"(", [num intValue],@")"];
}

return newTextLayer;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}






//Returns the number of stations in the line based on the data source. Since the chart will have a plot point for each field reading, this defines the number of records for each plot.
#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
return [[[DataSource sharedManager] finalFIELDreading]count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];
NSInteger valueCount =  [sharedManager.finalSTNreading count];
switch (fieldEnum) {
    case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
        if (index < valueCount) {
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
        }
        break;

    case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
     if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbol] == YES) {
         return [sharedManager.finalFIELDreading objectAtIndex:index];
         return [sharedManager.finalSTNreading objectAtIndex:index];
     }
        break;
}
return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}


-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
      [self initPlot];
}
```

Here is the method that creates the arrays for the graph I made it local and a block:

```
-(void)populateArraysWithFileData:(arrayLoadCompletion) compblock
{

    DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];

    [sharedManager.finalSTNreading removeAllObjects];
    [sharedManager.finalLINEreading removeAllObjects];
    [sharedManager.finalDAYreading removeAllObjects];
    [sharedManager.finalTIMEreading removeAllObjects];
    [sharedManager.finalFIELDreading removeAllObjects];
    [sharedManager.finalSreading removeAllObjects];
    [sharedManager.finalNreading removeAllObjects];
    sharedManager.FnumbersArray = nil;


    sharedManager.didFinishArrays = 0;

    NSUInteger finalCount = 0;

    // make a local string from the selected file data string

    NSString *text = @"";

    text = [sharedManager.selectedFile stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


    //NSLog(@"%@", text);
    //[text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // Remove newlines
    while ([text rangeOfString:@"\n"].location != NSNotFound)
        text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];

    while ([text rangeOfString:@"\t"].location != NSNotFound)
        text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@" "];


    // NSLog(@"%@", text);


    NSString *numbersonly = [[text componentsSeparatedByString:@" N "] objectAtIndex:1];


    //NSLog(@"%@", numbersonly);

    // Make an array with all of the formatted text seperated by a space
    sharedManager.FnumbersArray = [numbersonly componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];


    NSMutableArray * newDoubleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [sharedManager.FnumbersArray count]];
    for (NSString *string in sharedManager.FnumbersArray)
    {
        NSString *newString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
       // NSLog(@"%@",newString);
        NSInteger trueDouble = [newString integerValue];
        [newDoubleArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(trueDouble)]];
    }


   // NSLog(@"%@", newDoubleArray);

    finalCount = [sharedManager.FnumbersArray count];
    //NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)finalCount);

    //doubleValue or decimalValue

    //Make an array with just the station numbers that will become the x-axis
    for (int i = 0;i < finalCount;i += 7) {
        [sharedManager.finalSTNreading addObject:[sharedManager.FnumbersArray objectAtIndex:i]]; //this does not like being an int
    }

    //Make an array with just the Line data, start at the second index in the numbers array and iterare through it
    for (int i = 1;i < finalCount;i += 7) {
        [sharedManager.finalLINEreading addObject:[sharedManager.FnumbersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    // NSLog(@"%@", sharedManager.STNreading);

    //Make an array with just the day
    for (int i = 2;i < finalCount;i += 7) {
        [sharedManager.finalDAYreading addObject:[sharedManager.FnumbersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    //Make an array with just the Time
    for (int i = 3;i < finalCount;i += 7) {
        [sharedManager.finalTIMEreading addObject:[sharedManager.FnumbersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    //Make an array with just the field
    for (int i = 4;i < finalCount;i += 7) {
        [sharedManager.finalFIELDreading addObject:[newDoubleArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    //Make an array with just the S
    for (int i = 5;i < finalCount;i += 7) {
        [sharedManager.finalSreading addObject:[sharedManager.FnumbersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    //Make an array with just the N
    for (int i = 6;i < finalCount;i += 7) {
        [sharedManager.finalNreading addObject:[sharedManager.FnumbersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    sharedManager.didFinishArrays = 1;

    // NSLog(@"%@", sharedManager.finalSTNreading);
    // NSLog(@"%@", sharedManager.finalLINEreading);
    //  NSLog(@"%@", sharedManager.FDAYreading);
    // NSLog(@"%@", sharedManager.FTIMEreading);
    //  NSLog(@"%@", sharedManager.finalFIELDreading);
    //  NSLog(@"%@", sharedManager.FSreading);
    // NSLog(@"%@", sharedManager.FNreading);
    compblock(YES);
}
```

Here is the output from the log for the block and 'numberForPlot' :

```
2016-08-02 14:20:28.425 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] success
2016-08-02 14:20:28.438 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 0
2016-08-02 14:20:28.438 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 1
2016-08-02 14:20:28.438 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 2
2016-08-02 14:20:28.438 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 3
2016-08-02 14:20:28.439 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 4
2016-08-02 14:20:28.439 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 5
2016-08-02 14:20:28.439 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 6
2016-08-02 14:20:28.439 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 7
2016-08-02 14:20:28.439 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 8
2016-08-02 14:20:28.439 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 9
2016-08-02 14:20:28.440 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 10
2016-08-02 14:20:28.440 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 11
2016-08-02 14:20:28.440 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 12
2016-08-02 14:20:28.440 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 13
2016-08-02 14:20:28.440 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 14
2016-08-02 14:20:28.440 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 15
2016-08-02 14:20:28.441 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 16
2016-08-02 14:20:28.441 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 17
2016-08-02 14:20:28.441 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27082
2016-08-02 14:20:28.442 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27134
2016-08-02 14:20:28.442 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27149
2016-08-02 14:20:28.442 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27166
2016-08-02 14:20:28.442 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27177
2016-08-02 14:20:28.442 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27171
2016-08-02 14:20:28.442 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27141
2016-08-02 14:20:28.443 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27146
2016-08-02 14:20:28.443 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27224
2016-08-02 14:20:28.443 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27246
2016-08-02 14:20:28.443 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27240
2016-08-02 14:20:28.443 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27220
2016-08-02 14:20:28.443 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27223
2016-08-02 14:20:28.443 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27230
2016-08-02 14:20:28.444 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27228
2016-08-02 14:20:28.444 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27245
2016-08-02 14:20:28.444 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27248
2016-08-02 14:20:28.444 GeoData Grapher[4262:258562] 27237
```

Comment: When the datasource is called, does it return the correct values to the plot? If not, you might have a timing issue between when the plot is drawn and the data is available. Call `-reloadData` from the `+populateArraysWithFileData` method to fix that.

Comment: I also think it is a timing issue, as it seams that the segue happens before the arrays are fully populated. May I ask how would I call reloadData?

Comment: My apologies, it does return the correct values just before [self initPlot] is called

Comment: You can call `-reloadData` on individual plots or on the graph to reload all plots. Does the graph draw anything? Does `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` return the values you expect?

Comment: It looks like you're sending string values to the plot. Core Plot will call `doubleValue` or `decimalValue` on them to convert them to numeric values. Make sure there aren't any extra characters in there that would interfere with the conversion.

Comment: The app freezes before the graph is drawn, '-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:'  returns everything as expected.

Comment: Have you profiled the app to see where it's getting stuck?

Comment: @EricSkroch It seems to be fixed now, I changed the save format of the text file from ASCII to NSUTF8 encoding. Definitely a formatting issue

Comment: @EricSkroch I am still sitting with the same problem. I updated the method, made it a block and made it local instead of an pubic method. I have also tried making the finalFIELDreading array with objects Number from int, double and float. but nothing works. I then added a space in front of each row in the text file and suddenly some data was plotting but it was totally out as the arrays were not populated with the correct data.

Comment: I did profile the app but I couldn't get any useful info out of it or I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: Without the source file or a detailed format specification, it's impossible to tell if the `-populateArraysWithFileData:` method is working correctly. When you log the arrays at the end of the method, are they correct?

Comment: Hi, yes the method populates the arrays perfectly. I even did a string length to see if there are any unknown space in them but all is well. I have noticed that the problem begins when initPlot is called. Then the app freezes and the memory starts increasing until it crashes.

Comment: I did a new replaced my older core plot with the latest one but it does the same thing. I did the -reloadData as you mentioned but it still freezes. What boggles me is that when it worked the output of 'CPTScatterPlotFieldX' happens 3x meaning lets say there is 10 items to plot then the NSLog would be 0 to 9 but x3. Now that it doesn't, the output only happens once. I have no idea why that happens.

Comment: `-viewDidAppear:` calls `-initPlot` twice. That might be part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I identified the problem! I was dividing a integer with a float to get the Increment in configureAxis. Thanks for all the help Eric.